# How do I keep a users checked radio button on the next page with php?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to keep a checked radio button that has been selected by a user to pass to the same page, but for confirmation to allow the user to see what they entered is correct. This shouldn't be this hard, but I can't get it to quite work right.

Right now it is carrying over one checked, but it's just the last one and not impacting the user selection.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I think I have my code messed up now. I tried adding a session array, but now my verify page isn't loading. I like the idea of setting this up with a session array since I'm looking at passing this data into an email once they verify it. Here's the code for my two pages right now.

**order_form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HMC Promotional Items</title>
<link href="css/hmcpromo_secure.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<?php

session_start();

?>

</head>

<body>

<div id="logo"><img src="images/wfhm_bw_logo.jpg" width="272" height="114" /></div>

<div>
<h1>HMC Web Sites</h1>
<h2>Personalized Promotional Items</h2>
<br />
<p>
  The cost of items ordered will be deducted from branch P&amp;L. If this is a personal order, complete credit card information below. <strong>Order form must be filled out completely.</strong> If you do not receive an email acknowledgment of your order within 2 business days, please call 1-800-535-1395 to verify receipt.</p>
</div>


<form id="promo_order_form" name="promo_order_form" method="post" action="verify_order_form.php">

<div id="order_form">
<span id="sprytextfield7">
<label for="Order_Date">Order Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Order_Date" id="Order_Date" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield17">
    <label for="Date_Needed">Date Needed:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Date_Needed" id="Date_Needed" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield16">
    <label for="AU">AU #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="AU" id="AU" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    (Required for ALL orders, including credit card orders)
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield15">
    <label for="Approved">Approved by:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Approved" id="Approved" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    (Managers approval required)
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield5">
    <label for="mgrEmail">Manager Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mgrEmail" id="mgrEmail" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield14">
    <label for="Contact">Contact:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Contact" id="Contact" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield13">
    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield12">
    <label for="Phone1">Phone #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Phone1" id="Phone1" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield8">
<label for="Fax">Fax #:</label>
<input type="text" name="Fax" id="Fax" />
<span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield9">
<label for="MAC">MAC #:</label>
<input type="text" name="MAC" id="MAC" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield10">
    <label for="Ship">Ship to:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Ship" id="Ship" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield11">
    <label for="Attention">Attention:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Attention" id="Attention" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>

<div id="personal_form">
  <div id="personal_header">PERSONAL ORDERS ONLY:</div>

  <span id="spryradio1">
  <label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Visa" value="">
    <input name="cc" type="radio" id="Visa" value="Visa"/>
    Visa</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Master" value="">
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="Master" id="Master" />
    Mastercard</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Amex" value="">
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="Amex" id="Amex" />
    Amex</label>
</span>

  <span id="sprytextfield21">
  <label for="CardNum">Card Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="CardNum" id="CardNum" />
  <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
  <br />
  <br />

  <span id="sprytextfield18">
  <label for="exp">EXP:</label>
  <input name="exp" type="text" id="exp" value="MM/YY" size="10" maxlength="5" />
</span>

  <span id="sprytextfield20">
  <label for="cvs">CVS #:</label>
  <input name="cvs" type="text" id="cvs" size="5" maxlength="3" />
  <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <span id="sprytextfield19">
  <label for="auth">Name on Card:</label>
  <input name="auth" type="text" id="auth" size="40" />
</span>
</div>

<div id="delivery">
    <p>Please allow 3 weeks for delivery.
    <br />
    <br />
    Orders will ship via UPS Ground. Individual product styles will ship separately.
  </p>
</div>

    <br />
<ul>
  <li class="clear">PERSONALIZATION INFORMATION</li>
</ul>

<div id="pers_form">
<span id="sprytextfield3">
    <label for="First">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="First" id="First" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>

<span id="sprytextfield2">
    <label for="Last">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Last" id="Last" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span><br /><br />

<span id="sprytextfield4">
    <label for="Phone2">Phone #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Phone2" id="Phone2" />
    <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>

<span id="sprytextfield1">
    <label for="Email2">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email2" id="Email2" />
    <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
</div>

<div id="totals_header">
TOTAL COST
</div>

    <br />
<ul>
  <li>ITEM</li>
</ul>

<div id="item_form">
  <h3>Executive Metal Grip Roller</h3>
    <input name="ItemNum" type="hidden" id="ItemNum" value="EMGR" />
    <br />
    <input name="ItemPrice" type="text" id="ItemPrice" value="$1.10 Each" size="12" readonly="readonly" />
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield6">
<label for="Qty">Qty (Minimum 300):</label>
<input name="Qty" type="text" id="Qty" size="10" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span><span class="textfieldMinValueMsg">The entered value is less than the minimum required.</span></span><br />
    <br />
    <label for="Total">Total:</label>
    <input name="Total" type="text" id="Total" size="25" readonly="readonly" />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    <br />
</div>

<div id="totals_form">
  <label for="Subtotal">Subtotal</label>
  <input name="Subtotal" type="text" id="Subtotal" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="Sales_Tax">Sales Tax (MN only)</label>
  <input name="Sales_Tax" type="text" id="Sales_Tax" size="15" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="P_H">Packaging and Handling</label>
  <input name="P_H" type="text" id="P_H" value="$3.75" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
  <br />
  <br />  
  <label for="Freight">Freight</label>
  <input name="Freight" type="text" id="Freight" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
  <br />
  <hr />
  <label for="Totals">Total</label>
  <input name="Totals" type="text" id="Totals" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div class="clear"><!--CLEAR--></div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1", "email", {isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2", "none");
var sprytextfield3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield3", "none");
var sprytextfield4 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield4", "phone_number", {isRequired:false, useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield5 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield5", "email", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield6 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield6", "integer", {minValue:300});
var sprytextfield7 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield7", "date", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield8 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield8", "phone_number", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield9 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield9", "integer", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield10 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield10", "none");
var sprytextfield11 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield11", "none");
var sprytextfield12 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield12", "phone_number", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield13 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield13", "email", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield14 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield14");
var sprytextfield15 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield15");
var sprytextfield16 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield16", "integer");
var sprytextfield17 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield17", "date", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var spryradio1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationRadio("spryradio1", {isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield18 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield18", "none", {isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield19 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield19", "none", {isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield20 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield20", "integer", {isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield21 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield21", "integer", {isRequired:false});
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**verify_order_form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HMC Promotional Items</title>
<link href="css/hmcpromo_secure.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['Visa'];
$_SESSION['Master'];
$_SESSION['Amex'];



//Order Form Var
$Order_Date = strip_tags($_POST['Order_Date']);
$Date_Needed = strip_tags($_POST['Date_Needed']);
$AU = strip_tags($_POST['AU']);
$Approved = strip_tags($_POST['Approved']);
$mgrEmail = strip_tags($_POST['mgrEmail']);
$Contact = strip_tags($_POST['Contact']);
$Email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
$Phone1 = strip_tags($_POST['Phone1']);
$Fax = strip_tags($_POST['Fax']);
$MAC = strip_tags($_POST['MAC']);
$Ship = strip_tags($_POST['Ship']);
$Attention = strip_tags($_POST['Attention']);

//Personal Order Form Var
//$Visa = strip_tags($_POST['Visa']);
//$Master = strip_tags($_POST['Master']);
//$Amex = strip_tags($_POST['Amex']);
$CardNum = strip_tags($_POST['CardNum']);
$exp = strip_tags($_POST['exp']);
$cvs = strip_tags($_POST['cvs']);
$auth = strip_tags($_POST['auth']);

//Personalization Form Var
$First = strip_tags($_POST['First']);
$Last = strip_tags($_POST['Last']);
$Phone2 = strip_tags($_POST['Phone2']);
$Email2 = strip_tags($_POST['Email2']);

//Item Form Var and Math
$ItemNum = strip_tags($_POST['ItemNum']);
$ItemPrice = strip_tags($_POST['ItemPrice']);
$ItemNum = strip_tags($_POST['ItemNum']);
$Qty = strip_tags($_POST['Qty']);
$Total = strip_tags($_POST['Total']);

//Totals Form Math
$Subtotal = strip_tags($_POST['Subtotal']);
$Sales_Tax = strip_tags($_POST['Sales_Tax']);
$P_H = strip_tags($_POST['P_H']);
$Freight = strip_tags($_POST['Freight']);
$Totals = strip_tags($_POST['Totals']);

?> 

</head>

<body>

<div id="logo"><img src="images/wfhm_bw_logo.jpg" width="272" height="114" /></div>

<div>
<h1>Executive Metal Grip Roller</h1>
<h2>Personalized Promotional Items</h2>
<br />
<p>
  The cost of items ordered will be deducted from branch P&amp;L. If this is a personal order, complete credit card information below. <strong>Order form must be filled out completely.</strong> If you do not receive an email acknowledgment of your order within 2 business days, please call 1-800-535-1395 to verify receipt.</p>
</div>

<form id="promo_order_form" name="promo_order_form" method="post" action="">

<div id="order_form">
<span id="sprytextfield7">
<label for="Order_Date">Order Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Order_Date" id="Order_Date" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Order_Date) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield17">
    <label for="Date_Needed">Date Needed:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Date_Needed" id="Date_Needed" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Date_Needed) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield16">
    <label for="AU">AU #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="AU" id="AU" value='<?php echo htmlentities($AU) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    (Required for ALL orders, including credit card orders)
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield15">
    <label for="Approved">Approved by:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Approved" id="Approved" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Approved) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    (Managers approval required)
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield5">
    <label for="mgrEmail">Manager Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mgrEmail" id="mgrEmail" value='<?php echo htmlentities($mgrEmail) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield14">
    <label for="Contact">Contact:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Contact" id="Contact" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Contact) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield13">
    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Email) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield12">
    <label for="Phone1">Phone #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Phone1" id="Phone1" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Phone1) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield8">
<label for="Fax">Fax #:</label>
<input type="text" name="Fax" id="Fax" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Fax) ?>' />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield9">
    <label for="MAC">MAC #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="MAC" id="MAC" value='<?php echo htmlentities($MAC) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield10">
    <label for="Ship">Ship to:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Ship" id="Ship" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Ship) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield11">
    <label for="Attention">Attention:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Attention" id="Attention" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Attention) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>

<div id="personal_form">
  <div id="personal_header">PERSONAL ORDERS ONLY:</div>

  <span id="spryradio1">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="Visa" <?php echo if($_SESSION['cc'] == "Visa"){'checked="checked"';} ?> id="Visa"  />
    Visa</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="Master" <?php echo if($_SESSION['cc'] == "Master"){'checked="checked"';} ?> id="Master" />
    Mastercard</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="Amex" <?php echo if($_SESSION['cc'] == "Amex"){'checked="checked"';} ?> id="Amex" />
    Amex</label>
</span>

  <span id="sprytextfield21">
  <label for="CardNum">Card Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="CardNum" id="CardNum" value='<?php echo htmlentities($CardNum) ?>' />
  <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
  <br />
  <br />

  <span id="sprytextfield18">
  <label for="exp">EXP:</label>
  <input name="exp" type="text" id="exp" size="10" maxlength="5" value='<?php echo htmlentities($exp) ?>' />
  </span>

  <span id="sprytextfield20">
  <label for="cvs">CVS #:</label>
  <input name="cvs" type="text" id="cvs" size="5" maxlength="3" value='<?php echo htmlentities($cvs) ?>' />
  <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <span id="sprytextfield19">
  <label for="auth">Name on Card:</label>
  <input name="auth" type="text" id="auth" size="40" value='<?php echo htmlentities($auth) ?>' />
</span>
</div>

<div id="delivery">
    <p>Please allow 3 weeks for delivery.
    <br />
    <br />
    Orders will ship via UPS Ground. Individual product styles will ship separately.
  </p>
</div>

    <br />
<ul>
  <li class="clear">PERSONALIZATION INFORMATION</li>
</ul>

<div id="pers_form">
<span id="sprytextfield3">
    <label for="First">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="First" id="First" value='<?php echo htmlentities($First) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>

<span id="sprytextfield2">
    <label for="Last">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Last" id="Last" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Last) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span><br /><br />

<span id="sprytextfield4">
    <label for="Phone2">Phone #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Phone2" id="Phone2" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Phone2) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>

<span id="sprytextfield1">
    <label for="Email2">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email2" id="Email2" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Email2) ?>' />
    <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
</div>

<div id="totals_header">
TOTAL COST
</div>

    <br />
<ul>
  <li>ITEM</li>
</ul>

<div id="item_form">
  <h3>Executive Metal Grip Roller</h3>
    <input name="ItemNum" type="hidden" id="ItemNum" value="EMGR" />
    <br />
    <input name="ItemPrice" type="text" id="ItemPrice" value="$1.10 Each" size="12" readonly="readonly" />
    <br />
    <br />
<span id="sprytextfield6">
<label for="Qty">Qty (Minimum 300):</label>
<input name="Qty" type="text" id="Qty" size="10" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Qty) ?>' />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span><span class="textfieldMinValueMsg"><br />The entered value is less than the minimum required.</span></span><br />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <label for="Total">Total:</label>
    <input name="Total" type="text" id="Total" size="25" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div id="totals_form">
  <label for="Subtotal">Subtotal</label>
  <input name="Subtotal" type="text" id="Subtotal" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="Sales_Tax">Sales Tax (MN only)</label>
  <input name="Sales_Tax" type="text" id="Sales_Tax" size="15" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="P_H">Packaging and Handling</label>
  <input name="P_H" type="text" id="P_H" value="$3.75" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
  <br />
  <br />  
  <label for="Freight">Freight</label>
  <input name="Freight" type="text" id="Freight" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
  <br />
  <hr />
  <label for="Totals">Total</label>
  <input name="Totals" type="text" id="Totals" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div id="thank_you">
    <center><h3>Thank you for your order!</h3>
    <p class="font_red">Please verify the information and click the button to submit your order.</p>
    <br />
    <input name="Confirm" type="submit" class="font_bold" value="Confirm" />
    </center>
</div>

<div class="clear"><!--CLEAR--></div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1", "email", {isRequired:false, useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2", "none", {validateOn:["change"]});
var sprytextfield3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield3", "none", {validateOn:["change"]});
var sprytextfield4 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield4", "phone_number", {isRequired:false, useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield5 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield5", "email", {validateOn:["change"], useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield6 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield6", "integer", {minValue:300, validateOn:["change"]});
var sprytextfield7 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield7", "date", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield8 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield8", "phone_number", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield9 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield9");
var sprytextfield10 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield10");
var sprytextfield11 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield11");
var sprytextfield12 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield12", "phone_number", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield13 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield13", "email", {validateOn:["change"], useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield14 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield14");
var sprytextfield15 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield15");
var sprytextfield16 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield16", "integer");
var sprytextfield17 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield17", "date", {useCharacterMasking:true});
var spryradio1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationRadio("spryradio1", {isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield18 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield18", "none", {isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield19 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield19", "none", {isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield20 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield20", "integer", {isRequired:false});
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier when you start with one credit card first and if you get it to work to extend it to three?

Comment: On "the page it should be passing to", why do you have it putting checked="checked" on all three inputs?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "keep"? Do you want php to remember what values are posted once the form is submitted? Or can the user post the form multiple times with different values? In case of the first, check out my `$_SESSION` solution below. In case of the second scenario just use one of the `$_POST` examples below

Comment: Okay, wow, thanks everybody for all the responses. Don't mean to be confusing.
I want this page to post the user selected radio button: order_form.php
I want this page to show them which card type they chose and then they'll submit for the order to be emailed out: verify_order_form.php
So on the verify_order_form page I want their selected card to still be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the `$_SESSION` method I showed earlier

Use this for reading the value:

```
$cc = strip_tags($_POST['cc']);
```

And this for checking it in the form:

```
<span id="spryradio1">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="Visa" <?php echo if($cc == "Visa"){'checked="checked"';} ?> id="Visa"  />
    Visa</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="Master" <?php echo if($cc == "Master"){'checked="checked"';} ?> id="Master" />
    Mastercard</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="Amex" <?php echo if($cc == "Amex"){'checked="checked"';} ?> id="Amex" />
    Amex</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!! That worked. I had use the slightly tweaked version from farinspace and phirschybar, but it works now. So excited for that. I had another thought though. I wasn't really thinking ahead on this and when you mentioned sessions I started to wonder if I'd need a session to pass all of the form data, including this radio button selection, to the email(s) that will be processed once the order is verified? If you have any thoughts on that, thanks.

Comment: In your case you don't really need them, just pass submit the values from order_form.php to verify_order_form.php and after submitting the verify form read the values from the `$_POST` array and mail them. A session would come in handy if you had to submit the order form, have some unrelated pages after that and finally needed the values again in the verify form. Check out [this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) tutorial about how and when to use them

Answer (score 2):

You can check the $_POST array for that variable and then set the  checked state. Like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="example" value="1"<?php echo 'Visa' == $_POST['cc'] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
```

Comment: always use `<?php` some production INIs do not have `<?` (short_open_tag) configured, this will make your code more compatible also consider using `checked="checked"` as others have pointed out here

Answer (score 0):

For each input radio field, try using `<?php  echo 'checked="checked"' if $_POST['cc']=='Master'; ?>` (changing 'Master' to match to value of the radio box value for each. Just using `<?php  echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>` guarantees that the last one will be checked, since each radio button will have `'checked="checked"'` on them.

Comment: I tried this, but it broke the page from loading at all. I copied it as you have it.

Comment: ah, I usually code in Ruby, PHP was a while ago, so I think I kind of used ruby-ish syntax here. @Mark got it best :)